# PHP Notification System

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a notification system that works with the following codes

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$.get('/codes/php/nf.php', function(data) {
$('#check').html(data);});
});
setInterval(function(){$.get('/codes/php/nf.php', function(data) {
$('#check').html(data);});
}, 10000);
```

PHP:

```
   //Database stuff would be here
    $na = $num_rows; //Amount of notifications
    if($na == "1"){
    $nt="Notification";
    } else {
    $nt="Notifications";
    }
    if($na != "0"){
    echo "<a href='#'>$na $nt</a>";
    } else {
    exit;
    }
```

HTML: (It's a tipsy -- jQuery plugin -- tooltip)

```
title="<span id='check'>"
```

My only problem is when there is 0 notifications ($na = 0) a blank tooltip is displayed, and it looks really bad. So basically I can't have the 'title=' if I want to get rid of this problem, but I don't have any ideas. Anybody know I can fix this?

Ok, so I found out that I can't use this: title="" at all because even when there is no data at all, the tooltip is still being displayed.

Comment: Show us the element that the title attribute is on.

Comment: <img src="/images/logo.png" id="headimg" title="<span id='check'>">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try change

```
function(data) {
   $('#check').html(data);
}
```

with this :

```
function(data) {
   if (data != '') { 
      $('#check').html(data);
   }
}
```